# How to remove extra field from LAS file with laspy

Tags: las, laspy

I have LAS files with a useless extra scalar field (named "tree") that I would like to remove.

I tried the following code to create a new LAS file, copy each field of the orginal LAS file into the new LAS file, except the unwanted field.

```
import laspy

LASInput = laspy.file.File('foo.las', mode = 'r')
LASOutput = laspy.file.File('bar.las', mode = "w", header = LASInput.header)

#Lets copy all the existing data from input file:
for dimension in LASInput.point_format:
    print(dimension.name)
    if not(dimension.name == 'tree'):
        LASOutput.writer.set_dimension(dimension.name, LASInput.reader.get_dimension(dimension.name))
    
LASOutput.close()
LASInput.close()
```

But the resulting LAS file still contains the field "tree". I guess the header also has to be modified so I tried this approach, creating a new header:

```
import laspy

LASInput = laspy.file.File('D:\\foo.las', mode = 'r')
LASOutput = laspy.file.File('D:\\bar.las', mode = "w", header = laspy.header.Header(1.3))

#Lets create the extra fields
NamesOutput = [i.name for i in LASOutput.point_format]
for dimension in LASInput.point_format:
    print(dimension.name)
    if not(dimension.name == 'tree'):
        if not(dimension.name in NamesOutput):
            LASOutput.define_new_dimension(name = dimension.name, data_type = 5, description ='blabla')

#Lets copy all the existing data from the imput file
for dimension in LASInput.point_format:
    print(dimension.name)
    if not(dimension.name == 'tree'):
        LASOutput.writer.set_dimension(dimension.name, LASInput.reader.get_dimension(dimension.name))

LASOutput.close()
LASInput.close()

print('ok')
```

This works, but I find it rather inelegant, and also I did not find a way to get the fromat of the fields in the input header, in my code I used data_type=5, which is likely to be incorrect. Is there not a way to duplicate the input header and then to discard the unwanted field from the header?

Comment: Why not doing it with [las2las](http://lastools.org/download/las2las_README.txt) from `LAStools`? It should look like `las2las -i input.las -remove_vlr 0 -o output.las`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion JRR.
The reason to do it in python is that I do other data manipulation on the las file, so I would have prefer to do everything in python.
Nevertheless las2las is also fine, it seems to work, but the output file has the same size as the input file, so I guess data of this scalar filed was not present anyway in the input file.